# Redis session Django : KeyError when reading from session

Tags: python, django, session, redis, django-sessions

I am using Django 1.5.2 , Redis server 2.6.7 , redis-py package 2.8 , and django-redis-sessions 0.4.0 on an UBUNTU 12.04 server.

I have set redis session engine, ran redis-server. I use request.session['myKey'] to access a key in the session. Randomly I receive the proper value, but sometimes KeyError exception occur!!! I even check TTL of variables in Redis and all keys exist and not expired!

Amazing note is that myKey is available! and even readable as sometimes I can receive its value!

Any idea?